# How modify hibernate hbm.xml to get rid of - org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i will be specific as i can,so i want just ask for litle help with modification of this hbm.xml file

I have this file in my hibernate mappings

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.Dealer" table="book_dealer">
    <id column="idBook_dealer" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="domain" column="idMain_domain"
        not-null="true" class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.main.Domain" />
    <many-to-one name="activeData" column="idBook_dealerData"
        class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" />
    <set name="historyData" inverse="true">
        <key column="idBook_dealer" />
        <one-to-many class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" />
    </set>
    <property name="status" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

and this is associations:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.DealerData" table="book_dealerData">
    <id column="idBook_dealerData" name="id" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="registration" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="taxNumber" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="timestamp" not-null="true" />
    <property name="authorUserId" column="idAuthor" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="dealer" column="idBook_dealer"
        not-null="true" class="sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.Dealer" />
    <property name="channel" not-null="false">
        <type name="sk.bantip.core.enums.GenericEnumUserType">
            <param name="enumClass">sk.bantip.hotel.server.dao.book.Channel</param>
            <param name="identifierMethod">getValue</param>
            <param name="valueOfMethod">getByCode</param>
        </type>
    </property>
    <property name="street" not-null="false" />
    <property name="number" not-null="false" />
    <property name="zip" not-null="false" />
    <property name="city" not-null="false" />
    <property name="country" not-null="false" />
    <property name="telephone" not-null="false" />
    <property name="email" not-null="false" />
</class>
```

i found some guides which says using cascade operations, when i get

> org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:

but dont know which use, i know about cascade="all" but i dont know whether will be works in this case,
i use this method to save/update:

```
public void ajaxNameListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {         
     for(DealerListView diler : dealerList) {
      if(diler.getDealerId() == getSelectedDealerId()) {
         diler.setDealerId(selectedDealerId);   
         DealerData dilerko = new DealerData();
         dilerko.setName(selectedDealerName);
         Dealer dealer = BeanFactory
                 .getHotelDAOService(Dealer.class)
                 .findOne(selectedDealerId);    

          dealer.setActiveData(dilerko);
BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(Dealer.class).update(dealer);// line 220 - in stacktrace is (at sk.bantip.hotel.web.controller.SalesController.ajaxNameListener(SalesController.java:220))       
   }  
    }
}
```

can somone give me a advice based on this situation? i think that some change must be made in these hbm.xml files,on some cascade operations but not sure about this which will be,Please left me here some post, I will be glad for any help
Thank you and have a nice day.

Edit:  and in child class DealerData i have a **private** properties, not sure about that but maybe will be need add this attribute `access="field"` in DealerData.hbm.xml? because this allow Hibernate to read the value from the private variable instead of the public property.

Answer (score 0):

Not being a strong advocate of cascades, as the decision you make in your HBM.XML whether to cascade or not has to be consistent through your entire application, plus you not being so sure about which type of cascade you want, I'd rather stick with a simpler approach. Would it be a bad idea in your use case to add something like :

```
someDealerDataDAO.persist(dilerko);
```

just before the statement that provokes the error.

Comment: thanks for post, hmm in this DAOService i have just some save,saveOrUpdate,update method, i dont write that DAOService method i just using this for saveing to DB,i tried all this method with same stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

`cascade` is basically used in parent-child relationship (e.g. one-to-one, many-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many associations).

While defining child relationship in Parent class' mapping file, if you specify `cascade = "save-update"`, it will work like the following:

Whenever you save an instance of Parent class, if any child instances are associated with it, they also get saved (if transient) / updated (if already persisted). In this case you won't get the `'TransientObjectException'`.

But if you have specified `cascade = "refresh"`, it will work like the following:

Whenever you save a parent class' instance, only that instance will be saved. If any child class' instances are associated with that, they won't be saved/updated.

Having said this, if child class' instances are not persisted to database, it will simply throw `'TransientObjectException'`. To avoid this, you have to save the child class' instances manually before saving the parent class' instance.

Have a look at the different cascade options with example [here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-cascade-example-save-update-delete-and-delete-orphan/).

Comment: aha,ok thank you, but i confused in this case when my Dealer and DealerData both have in their hbm.xml files <many-to-one> tags, each of them referenced with one another,e.g i want update property of DealerData,so which cascade operations is suitable in this case?

Comment: Your case is called "bi-directional relationship". The rule for cascade is same. If you specify `cascade = "save-update"` in both mapping files, it will work like: if you save `Dealer`, associated `DealerData` will also be saved. If you save `DealerData`, associated `Dealer` will also be saved. It completely depends on where you specify `cascade`.

Comment: aha yes understand thank you again you help me clarify this, so not i needed specify cascade in both mapping files if i want make save/update only in my DealerData class i just put in this to DealerData.hbm.xml right? ask on this because i have declared cascade="save-update in both files"  and i get constraint violationException on Foreign Key in DealerData - "column id_dealer cannot be null"  when i want update some property from DealerData.class,or maybe this exception dont depend on this,i not sure

Comment: What is your requirement? Do you want to save `Dealer` while you save `DealerData` or you want to save `DealerData` while you save `Dealer`?

Comment: I already solve this so its non-actual,i succesfully updating to Db so its ok:) but have new problem on the scene, for example i want update one of my property from DealerData, i provide that update,a new value is in DB, but rest of properties is also overwritten to NULL also, is some general pattern what i can use my method above, to tell hibernate update only required property and rest remains unchanged?

Comment: It definitely has a solution but I recommend that you post it as a separate question & provide its link here so that I can easily refer to it. As far as this question is concerned, if you find my answer useful, please accept it.